# Set column width for QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qtreewidget

Is there any way to set column width for QTreeWidget from code? I want to chage default width of  first column. I'm using PySide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[QHeaderView::resizeSection()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#resizeSection) should do the trick, in C++ it would look like this:

```
myTreeWidget->headerView()->resizeSection(0 /*column index*/, 100 /*width*/);
```

Comment: I think I can adopt it for PySide. Thanks

Comment: There is no function `headerView` in `QTreeWidget`. I think you really meant to use `QTreeWidget::header()` (at least for Qt5 - maybe the answer was for Qt4)

Answer (score 3):

In Pyside2 there is no `resizeSection`

you can use this in PySide2:

```
header = self.treeWidget.header()
header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
header.setStretchLastSection(False)
header.setSectionResizeMode(5, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

Answer (score 3):

For people looking for a C++ Qt solution (tested with 5.12):

```
// Important to call setMinimumSectionSize because resizeSection wont work if your width is less than the minimum
treeWidget->header()->setMinimumSectionSize(25);
treeWidget->header()->resizeSection(1 /*column index*/, 25 /*width*/);

// You might also need to use this if you want to limit the size of your last column:
treeWidget->header()->setStretchLastSection(false);
```