# Qt: How to fix column width for a QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to set the width of a column in my QTreeWidget to a fixed size. setColumnWidth() appears to have no effect, and the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691525/set-column-width-for-qtreewidget) results in the compiler error " 'headerView': is not a member of 'QTreeWidget' ".

I am using Qt 4.7.4.

Answer (score 2):

QHeaderView::resizeSection() may work for you. Try doing the following code:

`treeWidget->header()->resizeSection(index, width);`

Comment: This is the same suggestion as in the link above. It gives me the error: C2039: 'headerView' : is not a member of 'QTreeWidget'

Comment: just `header`, not `headerView`